how to pair and connect with BlueZ C API
I am trying to use the BlueZ C API to perform pairing and connection with a bt classic device.
The requirement is to use the C API (hci_lib) to perform all the needed actions just like the two mentioned above. Initially I've managed to almost arrange the pairing by using the int hci_authenticate_link(int dd, uint16_t handle, int to) function which however in turn asked me through the blueman applet the confirmation for the pairing.
I've tried to play around the int hci_write_stored_link_key(int dd, bdaddr_t *bdaddr, uint8_t *key, int to) function thinking that by setting a key before the authentication I will not be bothered anymore with any confirmation after.
That was a very big mistake.
Once I have called hci_write_stored_link_key function with an arbitrary key value I've no longer passed the authentication as before (by being asked for the confirmation).
Since then then the hci_authenticate_link function just immediately returns - the symptom is that the implementation does not start the auth messages exchanges at all but it immediately returns after reading some kind of a state somewhere.
This is the most frustrating API I've ever had the occasion to work with.
Is there any way to let the pairing work without any confirmation by using such ugly API? Is there any way to remove that sort of flag/state written somewhere with the hci_write_stored_link_key call?
